# What is a package index file

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, files

In the following statement about "apt-get update" from [linux.die.net](http://linux.die.net/man/8/apt-get) is the term "package index file":

> Used to re-synchronize the package index files from their sources. ...

What exactly does "package index file" mean? Google has not given me any answer about this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The "package index files" contain information about the packages a package repository provides. APT stores them in `/var/lib/apt/lists`

Answer (score 4):

The package index file is a file that contains information about the packages present in a repository for use with `apt`. The format is described here:

https://wiki.debian.org/RepositoryFormat#A.diff.2FIndex_files

Answer (score 4):

The APT package index is essentially a database of available packages from the repositories defined in the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file and in the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` directory. To update the local package index with the latest changes made in the repositories, type the following:

```
sudo apt update
```

To upgrade your system, first, update your package index as outlined above, and then type:

```
sudo apt upgrade
```

I would suggest to read https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/package-management for further details.

Example:
CMD to run :

```
cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mysql.list
```

This command list the mysql repos. Visit http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ and you will find the actual hosted files.
Output:

```
deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ bionic mysql-apt-config
deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ bionic mysql-5.7
deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ bionic mysql-tools
#deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ bionic mysql-tools-preview
deb-src http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ bionic mysql-5.7
```