# Ubuntu Software when downlaoding something, goes to 14% then drops to 0% then begins really slow downloads

Tags: snap, snap-store

My OS is Ubuntu 20.04.3 Focal Fossa. Ubuntu Software is really slow today for some reason. Whatever application I try to download, it starts at 14%, then quickly drops back to 0%. Before this issue, I could download 300 MB software in 1 min. But know it takes at least ten mins to download a
80 MB software.
Here is the `snap list`

```
Name                               Version                     Rev    Tracking         Publisher   Notes
bare                               1.0                         5      latest/stable    canonical✓  base
core18                             20211028                    2253   latest/stable    canonical✓  base
core20                             20211129                    1270   latest/stable    canonical✓  base
gnome-3-28-1804                    3.28.0-19-g98f9e67.98f9e67  161    latest/stable    canonical✓  -
gnome-3-34-1804                    0+git.3556cb3               77     latest/stable/…  canonical✓  -
gnome-3-38-2004                    0+git.cd626d1               87     latest/stable    canonical✓  -
gtk-common-themes                  0.1-59-g7bca6ae             1519   latest/stable/…  canonical✓  -
kde-frameworks-5-qt-5-15-3-core20  5.87.0                      8      latest/stable    kde✓        -
kdenlive                           21.08.3                     46     latest/stable    kde✓        -
snap-store                         3.38.0-66-gbd5b8f7          558    latest/stable/…  canonical✓  -
snapd                              2.53.2                      14066  latest/stable    canonical✓  snapd
wine-platform-3-stable             3.0.4                       14     latest/stable    mmtrt       -
wine-platform-runtime              v1.0                        274    latest/stable    mmtrt       -
```

Comment: Your mirror server is lagging. Wait a couple of days and try it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your download server in *Software & Updates* -> *Ubuntu Software* tab is lagging. Usually this is a temporary issue that goes away by itself. Wait a couple of days and try it again.

The package index files contain information about the packages a package repository provides. `apt` stores them in `/var/lib/apt/lists`. <sup>[source](https://askubuntu.com/a/550395/)</sup> If you get impatient and change the download server it will try to resynchronize the package index files from their new sources which requires downloading 100MB or more, often more than 200MB, and then if the new download server is slower than the old one you'll have to repeat the process in reverse and resynchronize the package index files again.

Comment: Thanks it went away!