# Thunderbird update link seems broken

Tags: apt, 20.04, upgrade, thunderbird

Using Ubuntu 20.04.3 sudo apt upgrade fails: Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
Using browser to:
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/t/thunderbird/thunderbird_78.14.0+build1-0ubuntu0.20.04.2_amd64.deb

see a file but it cannot be downloaded.
using wget fails:
Read error at byte 6511313/50527696 (Connection reset by peer)

Using different server gives same result.
Any suggestions please?
Thank you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Unable to duplicate the problem: On my Firefox browser, that link works and the deb downloads properly. Perhaps the mirror you tried happened to be in the midst of a sync or some other transient problem occurred. Try again.

Answer (score 0):

Your download server in Software & Updates -> *Ubuntu Software* tab has not updated the Thunderbird package to version 78.14.0 yet. Usually this is a temporary issue that goes away by itself. When I tried `wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/t/thunderbird/thunderbird_78.14.0+build1-0ubuntu0.20.04.2_amd64.deb` wget manually downloaded the Thunderbird .deb file successfully. I recommend trying `sudo apt upgrade` again because the problem appears to have gone away by itself. If that doesn't work wait a couple of days and try it again.

The package index files contain information about the packages a package repository provides. apt stores them in `/var/lib/apt/lists`. <sup>[source](https://askubuntu.com/a/550395/)</sup> If you get impatient and change the download server it will try to resynchronize the package index files from their new sources which requires downloading 100MB or more, often more than 200MB, and then if the new download server is slower than the old one you'll have to repeat the process in reverse and resynchronize the package index files again.

Comment: Thanks, it seems UFW blocks Canonical all of a sudden. I don't know why but issue is resolved.